# How to fix "script.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: ..." JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a little project, and I came across the following JavaScript error:

```
script.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onkeyup')
at script.js:5:18
```

Here is the HTML & JavaScript code I used:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  var filter = document.getElementById("the-filter"),
      list = document.querySelectorAll("#the-list li");
      
  filter.onkeyup = () => {
    let search = filter.value.toLowerCase();
 
    for (let i of list) {
      let item = i.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      if (item.indexOf(search) == -1) { i.classList.add("hide"); }
      else { i.classList.remove("hide"); }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
#the-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#the-list a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#the-list li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

#the-list li:hover { 
    background: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#the-list li.hide { 
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="the-filter" placeholder="Search The Marketplace..."/>
            
                <ul id="the-list">
                    <a href="a_link.htm"><li>Item</li></a>
          <a href="a_link.htm"><li>Item1</li></a>
          <a href="a_link.htm"><li>Item2</li></a>
          <a href="a_link.htm"><li>Item3</li></a>
                </ul>
```

I understand what is causing this issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.. And it all works just fine when opened in the browser, except that it's displaying this error.

Comment: your snippet seems work how do you link your js and your html ?

Comment: I created a seperate .js file and linked it to my index.htm via <script src="script.js"></script> which I placed just above </body> (so pretty much the end of the document)

Comment: Are you sure you have an element with that ID? (double check typos etc)

Comment: Everything seems to be fine in the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the input DOM was not ready

try

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // your code
    // DOM ready
});
```

Comment: Just did, but still I get the same error as before.

Comment: hmm how are you importing/including the code? don't see the error running the snippet. probably is something external, it's clear that the dom is not ready sometime when you try to assign onkeyup function

Comment: I created a seperate .js file and linked it to my index.htm via <script src="script.js"></script> which I placed just above </body> (so pretty much the end of the document)

I think I found the source of the issue. When I open a .htm element which contains these tags it doesn't display the error, but if I open another .htm document which doesn't, then it displayed the errors.

I just noticed this now. But I'm not really sure what to do, without adding some random object to the code which will ruin the design or the CSS code.